# why do i have to declare javascript variable with an empty value?

Tags: javascript

why must i declare the `var msg = ' ';` and not just `var msg;`  and also why `msg += 'Round ' + roundNumber + ':';'`  and not just `msg = 'Round ' + roundNumber + ':';`.... why should i add + sign before equals ?

```
var score = [24, 32, 17];
    var arrayLength = score.length;
    var roundNumber = 0;
    var i;
    var msg = '';

    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      roundNumber = (i + 1);
      msg += 'Round ' + roundNumber + ':'; 
      msg += score[i] + '</br>'
    }

    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = msg;
```

output of the above code:

```
Test 1:24
Test 2:32
Test 3:17
```

output of the code when msg is declared only rather than giving an empty value and assigning msg without the plus (+) sign:

```
Test 3:17
```

Comment: test it........

Comment: Second question-because you're appending to the string in a loop, not replacing it. First question-because it would look silly with an "undefined" in the beginning. All this is trivially testable in the JS console.

Comment: As you can see from your tests: because they do different things? If you want the former output, you need to use the appropriate initialisation and operators.

Comment: @zack Please note the corrections to your accepted answer in my comment; a number of things in it are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused a number of Javascript concepts.

Firstly, Javascript variables must be declared but do not have to be initialised.  To declare a Javascript variable, you use the `var` keyword.  For example, `var msg;` is valid Javascript code.  As well as declaring a variable, you can optionally initialise it using an = sign.  So, for example, `var msg = '';` declares the `msg` variable and initialises it to an empty string.  Importantly for you, if you do not initialise a Javascript variable, it is set to a special type of variable called `undefined`.

The second Javascript concept you have confused is assignment and calculation.  In Javascript, you use the `=` sign to assign a value to a variable.  So, for example `x = 1;` sets the value of the x variable to 1.  The `+=` operator is a shorthand operator.  So, `x += y;` is exactly the same as `x = x + y;`.  The crucial difference is that the `=` operator overwrites the existing value of the variable, whereas `+=` uses the existing value to calculate a new value.

So, in the specific case of your code, you have used the `+=` operator on the `msg` variable.  As explained, the `+=` operator performs a calculation on the existing value of the variable.  So, this is why you had to initialise your variable when you declared it - otherwise you would have been performing a `+=` on an `undefined` variable - which, in your case, does not perform the string concatenation that you expected.

The specific instances on when you should use what very much depends upon what the goal of your code is.

Comment: Technically they don't need to be declared in all environments; if it's being assigned to, for example, a browser will happily put it in the window scope. If you don't assign to it it's value is `undefined, not `null. The subsequent value of a `+=` on a `null` depends on the data type, e.g., `var a = null; a += 5` will result in `5` while `var b = null; b += 'hi'` will result in `nullhi`. If it's `undefined`, e.g., `var c;`, then `c += 5` will result in `NaN` and `c += 'hi'` will result in `undefinedhi`.